# Paramiko TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, ssh, aws-lambda, sftp, paramiko

I am currently trying to move file from SFTP to S3 bucket using Paramiko library in Lambda function in Python.
But facing type error.

My code:

```
def open_ftp_connection(ftp_host, ftp_port, ftp_username, ftp_password):
    '''
    Opens ftp connection and returns connection object
    '''
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        transport = paramiko.Transport(ftp_host, ftp_port)
    except Exception as e:
        return 'conn_error'
    try:
        transport.connect(username=ftp_username, password=ftp_password)
    except Exception as identifier:
        return 'auth_error'

    ftp_connection = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    return ftp_connection
```

`ftp_host` is `str` - `13.xxx.1xx.xx`
`ftp_port` is `str` - `22`
`ftp_username` is `str`

Error:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/transfer_data.py", line 159, in transfer_handler
    ftp_connection = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
  File "/var/task/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 165, in from_transport
    window_size=window_size, max_packet_size=max_packet_size
  File "/var/task/paramiko/transport.py", line 879, in open_session
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/var/task/paramiko/transport.py", line 973, in open_channel
    window_size = self._sanitize_window_size(window_size)
  File "/var/task/paramiko/transport.py", line 1970, in _sanitize_window_size
    return clamp_value(MIN_WINDOW_SIZE, window_size, MAX_WINDOW_SIZE)
  File "/var/task/paramiko/util.py", line 308, in clamp_value
    return max(minimum, min(val, maximum))
```

Comment: Port should be integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Vishnudev answered.

The Port should be given as integer.